# In QNetworkAccessManager, When IP is selected from list of IPs resolved DNS?

Tags: qt, http, qtwebkit, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

I'm using QnetworkAccessManager to make the HTTP request, I want to know when the FQDN is resolved(DNS resolution) to get the IP address or list of IP addresses.

How QNetworkAccessManager selects the IP from the list of resolved IPs to send the request?

Do QNetworkAccessManager keep the cache of DNS resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QNetworkAccessManager` uses `QAbstractSocket` including its ability to resolve host names. `QAbstractSocket` uses `QHostInfo::lookupHost` to get list of IPs (`QHostInfo::​addresses`) of specified host. `QAbstractSocket` tries to connect to each of `QHostInfo::​addresses` until connection is succeeded.

There is no way to know which address was used because `QNetworkAccessManager` doesn't expose used sockets to the user. You can get full list of addresses using `QHostInfo` public API.

`QHostInfo` has internal global cache which stores up to 128 items with max age of 1 minute.

Comment: thank you for info. in case of ant URL fired, does it only uses TCP or UDP protocol?  because I want to fire URL using QtWebkit and check on which IP address request goes.

Comment: HTTP(S) and FTP use TCP only.